# Ajax post servlet response timeout

Tags: ajax, apache, jakarta-ee, post

I use Apache common-fileupload to upload image to my sever successfully.Then I want to use progress listener to monitor progress and store progress into session when uploading image.I use fileupload servlet to upload file and another servlet to receive ajax request (post) to get session every 0.5 second. But I found that when i uploading image,ajax request time out,and when I stop upload in midway,ajax request successfully and response session value.I really don't know why,you can try it here: cloudimages.sinaapp.com